# challenging probability question on multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_1, X_2, X_3) ∼ Mult (n, 3, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2)$. Find $E(X_1X_2).$

I'm stuck.

I know  it should be $\sum(ab) p_{x_1x_2}(a,b).$

But how to calculate it ?

What else I know is that $a+b+c$ is $n$ while $c=x_3$.

Comment: I have tried to improve your text. You should learn to type in latex/MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2)=\frac{n}2$$

$$Var(X_1+X_2)=\frac{n}4=\mathbb{E}((X_1+X_2)^2)-\left(\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2) \right)^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1^2+2X_1X_2+X_2^2)=\frac{n+n^2}4$$

Hence, if you are able to compute $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)$, then you are done. Are you able to take it from here?

Comment: why (X1+X2)=n/2, Var(X1+X2)=n/4??

Comment: $X_1+X_2 \sim Bin(n, \frac12)$ right?

Comment: In general if $(X_1, \ldots, X_k) \sim Mult(n, k, p_1, \ldots, p_k)$, we have $\sum_{i \in S} X_i \sim Bin(n, \sum_{i \in S} p_i)$ where $S$ is some index set.

Comment: get it. Thanks!!!!